# Crash on launch - TestFlight builds XCODE 13.3

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I just upgraded XCODE to 13.3.1 and my app crashes on startup when installing from TestFilght. When I build it directly on the phone there is no issue with the app.

There are no crash logs and can't see the logs on the device itself. I don't know what will happen if I'll publish it to the store and I don't want to try. The app should work on TestFlight

I searched the internet and it's an Apple bug. So let me summarize all the solutions here-
Disabling bitcode (setting to NO)- is the only working solution- but I don't want to disable it.
If any of you have another solution please let me know!

Other solutions that didn't work-

- Updating XCODE to 13.4 - didn't help
- Adding "-Wl,-weak-lswift_Concurrency -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/swift"- didn't help
- Adding libswift_Concurrency.tbd in the "Link Binary    with Libraries" - didn't help

Comment: have you found solution? for me too only disabling 'include bitcode' helped me during delivering archive to appstoreconnect.